# HTML5 Video Autoplay: Same Video element attributes & properties set, works on one page doesn't on another

Tags: video, mobile, html5-video, autoplay

Admittedly a newb when it comes to using HTML vid elements, but my wheels are spinning here. Read a bunch of threads about outplay on mobile and the requirement of the "muted plays inline" elements. Knew it was going to be a tricky SoB to get working, but after playing around, I have my  elements autoplaying with no issues whatsoever on any desktop browsers. But on mobile, my  element only autoplays on one page of my site - where the rest of the pages it doesn't work.

**Mobile Autoplay Works:** https://frankieunderwater.com/supportive-materials/

**Mobile Autoplay Doesn't Work:** https://frankieunderwater.com

I'm not finding a lot of fruitful info searching how CSS relates to autoplaying - if at all, but am curious if that's causing the issue? Because the page that the  element works on mobile and autoplays the video is the BG so its set to a fixed position. The other pages the video element is in the page flow and the layout is controlled with flex.

Thanks in advance for any insights

Comment: Try adding `controls` to the videos to see if it's a slow loading issue. Also it seems your video must wait until full download to play because the metadata section (called **Moov** and required for playback) is at the back of the MP4 file. Maybe use a video tool like Handbrake or FFmpeg to move the header to front, research `mp4 faststart` or `mp4 Moov beginning`. In Handbrake the option is called `optimize for web` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will mess around with that today. What's weird, is the video on the /supportive-materials page that successfully autoplays on mobile is the largest video in terms of file size for the site because it's meant to be a full window BG. I do suspect loading is a factor, but odd that the biggest video autoplays - possible that one was exported differently too I guess. Will play around with some of those settings